# Getting Robots.txt Not Found 404 Error on Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt

I have created `robots.txt` in my root directory and when I navigate to my website address like `https://example.ca/robots.txt` I am able to see the rules

```
User-agent:*
Disallow: /captcha/
Disallow: /mailing/
Disallow: /assets/

Allow: /

Sitemap: https://domain.ca/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://domain.ca/sitemap.xml
```

But when I want to test the file in Google [robots.txt Tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598)

[image]

I am getting this error

[image]

I am however able to test the file at bottom of the page or see the live robots.txt

[image]

but still getting 404 error when entering to the page!

Comment: Wen you say you created the robots.txt, when did you do that?  Was it just created today?

Comment: Yes it is newly created file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can take up to 24 hours, the robot tester seems to a bit flakey after just putting your file up. Good thing at least is that you're not getting a **BLOCKED** response from the tester.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/submit-updated-robots-txt